# Clicking help-button in MessageBox loads help-link multiple times

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-4.0

When I show a `MessageBox` with `helpFilePath` set to some url, the url loads multiple times. It seems to me that the url loads a number of times equal to the number of my forms parents plus one.

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tewzaxwc(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1) the `HelpRequested` event will fire on the active form:

> When the user clicks Help button, the Help file specified in the
>   `helpFilePath` parameter is opened. The form that owns the message box
>   (or the active form) also receives the [HelpRequested](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.helprequested(v=vs.110).aspx) event.
>
> The helpFilePath parameter can be of the form *C:\path\sample.chm*
>   or */folder/file.htm*.

But I don't understand why raising the `HelpRequested` event on the parent forms should load the link from the child forms `MessageBox`.

Am I doing something I'm not supposed to?

This code will reproduce the behaviour:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // First button spawns new instances of the form
        var button1 = new Button { Text = "New Form" };
        Controls.Add(button1);
        button1.Click += delegate
        {
            using (var form = new Form1())
                form.ShowDialog();
        };

        // Second button shows the MessageBox with the help-button
        var button2 = new Button { Text = "Dialog", Left = button1.Right };
        Controls.Add(button2);
        button2.Click += delegate
        {
            MessageBox.Show(
                "Press Help", 
                "Caption", 
                MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
                MessageBoxIcon.None, 
                MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1, 
                0, // Default MessageBoxOption (probably not related to the behaviour) 
                "http://SomeHelpSite.com/MyOnlineHelp.htm");
        };
    }
}
```

Click "New Form" a couple of times:

[image]

Then click "Dialog":

[image]

Now, click the help-button:

[image]

On my computer this opens SomeHelpSite.com tree times:

[image]

Comment: Strange, confirmed also using LinqPad

Comment: Because internally (in the IL/CLR) they are referred to the same delegate block? I don't know too... It's just guessing. But which among the three `Form1` which you press your `Dialog` `Button`? If you press any of the three and the results are always the same, then it is possible that the `Form1s` are referring to the same delegate(?)

Comment: @Ian, when I use `form.ShowDialog();` the forms are modal, so I can press `Dialog` only in the last shown form. If I rewrite and do `new Form1().Show();` instead then only one link is opened when I press the help-button (from any form).

Comment: I see, so you pressed the last one. Indeed, this is interesting. If the button2.Click event handler is not made anonymous, what will happen? You may want to check if you actually go to the Button.Click event thrice or the problem disappear...

Comment: Same thing happens if I use named methods. And the `Button.Click` event fires only one time (confirmed with breakpoint).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found a way to block the undesidered behavior and, probably, an explanation  why this happens.

To block the opening of undesidered url after the first one you need to simply add an handler for the HelpRequested event. In this event you should inform the WinForms engine that you have handled the help request and no further action is required

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.HelpRequested += onHelpRequested;
    .....
}
protected void onHelpRequested(object sender, HelpEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

In this way, only one page is opened.

Now the explanation why this happens is, probably, reported at the MSDN page for the [Handled property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.helpeventargs.handled(v=vs.110).aspx) of the **HelpEventArgs** where you could find this statement:

> If you do not set this property to true the event will be passed to
>   Windows for additional processing.

**EDIT** Further tests shows that also without setting the Handled property to true, the simple fact that an event handler for the HelpRequested event exists stops the undesidered behavior

Comment: That is so strange! It means doing `HelpRequested += delegate { };` in the constructor will prevent the additional links from opening. Try explaining that one to codereview :) I'll accept this as an answer tomorrow unless someone explains why it's happening.